# How to use GET POST methods in Rscript?

Tags: html, r, ubuntu, cgi, rscript

I am trying to implement my R code as a web app. I found that we can do the above as CGI script in apache. I have installed `apache2` in my Ubuntu system and then enabled CGI using `sudo a2enmod cgi` and restarted the apache server `sudo service apache2 restart`.

After that I created a shell script `index.sh` made it executable `chmod 755 index.sh` and moved the script to cgi-bin folder `sudo mv index.sh /usr/lib/cgi-bin/`

**index.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

cat("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
cat("<html>")
cat("<body>")
cat("<p><em>Hello</em>, world!</p>")
v <- round(runif(10)*100, 0)  
cat("<p>", v, "</p>")
cat("</body>")
cat("</html>")
```

Then visited http://localhost/cgi-bin/index.sh and its giving successful result

> Hello, world!
>
> 53 90 25 67 2 29 48 28 91 49

But instead of passing varibles in the script I want to ask users (as a textbox submission) to input variables for random number generation

some thing like this

```
Range=user defined integer from textbox
Length=user defined integer from textbox
v <- round(runif(Length)*Range, 0)
```

How can I do this?

**EDIT 1**

I was searching everywhere for solution to this problem but so far I can get server environment variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

cat("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
cat("<html>")
cat("<body>")
cat("<p><em>Hello</em>, world!</p>")
cat("<form action='http://localhost/cgi-bin/index.sh' method='POST'>
  Range:<br>
  <input type='number' name='range' value='100'>
  <br>
  Length:<br>
  <input type='number' name='length' value='10'>
  <br><br>
  <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>")
cat(Sys.getenv("REQUEST_METHOD"))
if(Sys.getenv("REQUEST_METHOD")=="POST")
{
v <- round(runif(10)*100, 0)  # sample ten random integers from {0..10}
cat("<p>", v, "</p>")
}

cat("</body>")
cat("</html>")
```

but when I submit the result is pure garbage

> ‹ÍNÃ0„ï}Šáäà¦QÓ¦r|æ€¢¼€¸±%ÿDé†ªo“¢Šn;Ú™‘æ–‚—B§î*Å
>   … òÅxŸÏ×#.iôÝƒàùsJc€jÉ¥Ø0K48÷©UÞ¦3ñ¶wOÚE~1ú9ßÁM]ÃÞßŽŸL®€{szœ…pq˜tLÃâ´¢
>   Y³áKù)«b½^Ò?¹W{²ÿhñ‹ñWÍ½å¯ìyÒÁÑÝ}¼I¹|^-ç
>   v5¶{”êûÕE…zƒ]…bƒ…¿‘äÖo]

Comment: Though not exactly what you're suggesting, I instead recommend using something like [`OpenCPU`](http://opencpu.org/) or [`shiny`](http://shiny.rstudio.com/). This type of programming can get really complicated really quickly, so there is utility in capitalizing on testing and experience of others.

Comment: `plumber` or `fiery` would be far better, too. if you really need to use apache, then [`rapache`](http://rapache.net/) wld be better than relying on CGI.